# Trying to put a Html string to the WebView in Xamarin

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, webview

I have a little strange problem with the WebView in Xamarin (Visual Studio 2017)

**This scenario works:**
I am putting html content to the webview in the "OnCreate" event and the webview shows "Hello"

**This scenario doesn't work:**
I am creating a button control in the OnCreate and assign a click event. The clickevent Do fire so this works. But "Hello2" is not put to the WebView although I use the exact same code.

What could be the problem?

```js
<WebView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:id="@+id/LocalWebView">
</WebView>


        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main); Android.Content.Context context = ApplicationContext;
            Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar toolbar = FindViewById<Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar>(Resource.Id.toolbar);
            SetSupportActionBar(toolbar);


            //This works and shows: "Hello"
            WebView localWebView = FindViewById<WebView>(Resource.Id.LocalWebView);
            localWebView.SetWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()); // stops request going to Web Browser
            localWebView.LoadData("<html>Hello</html>", "text/html", "utf-8");



            Button button = new Button(context);
            button.Click += (sender, args) =>
            {
                //The click event fires but Hello2" is not put to the webview?
                Button btn = sender as Button;

                WebView localWebView2 = FindViewById<WebView>(Resource.Id.LocalWebView);
                localWebView2.SetWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()); // stops request going to Web Browser
                localWebView2.LoadData("<html>Hello2</html>", "text/html", "utf-8");
            };
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

It worked now when I did put the width and height to the WebView.
Strangely "fill_parent" or "match_parent" didn't expand the WebView.

```js
<WebView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="500px"
  android:layout_height="1000px"
  android:id="@+id/LocalWebView">
</WebView>
```